# cool as an adjective

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

When I describe a mountain that has a fairly low temperature, I use the adjective "cool"

> eg(1) The wilderness has a cool mountain.
> eg(2) The cool mountain posed a higher risk for the travelers

Grammarly always marks the usage for "word choice"
Why is it so? Is it a wrong adjective to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cool" is a mild, pleasant coldness, like the enjoyable sensation when you enter a shadow on a hot day.

You want to say "cold". Cold can cause harm, or make people shiver. Cool cannot.

(I don't know why Grammarly complains, but remember "cool" is also a slang word for something that is good, trendy or fashionable.)

Comment: Grammarly probably assumes the word is being used in the slang sense, and warns against it as being so overused as to be nearly meaningless, the same way it might warn against words like "nice" and "good".

Comment: Yes. You're right. It doesn't like "nice" and "good" too. :) @ThePhoton

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. @equin0x80

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to ascribe a temperature to a mountain. I would say "the cool mountain air", "the cool climate on the mountain", etc.

A "cool" temperature is usually expected to be pleasant, perhaps calling for a light jacket. A temperature that could be dangerously low is best described as "cold", not "cool".

Comment: There's nothing unusual about describing a mountain as *cold*.